# How to get Android OS download and upload speed programmatically

Tags: android, networking

How can I get ***current upload*** and ***download speed*** of my Android device ?

I am not talking about app specific download or upload system. I want to get something like this :

[image]

How can I determine my device speed like that way? I know, how to show info in notification bar. I just want to know the procedure to get download and upload speed.

Comment: Check my title please. I want achieve something like that. I tried with TrafifcStatus and WifiManager. None of them worked.

Comment: Please Check now @LinX64

Comment: Yes, exactly. @LinX64

Comment: "I want to get something like this" -- that's a screenshot of a home screen launcher, perhaps Cyanogen's. It would not appear to have anything to do with download and upload speed. To determine download speed, download something and time it. To determine upload speed, upload something and time it. I am not aware of any other options for determining transfer speeds.

Comment: take a look https://github.com/pragma-/networklog